# Plot Bode from FFT

Tags: fourier-analysis, fast-fourier-transform

I have data in excel (time and vibration), which I have done calculated fft for the data. Now, I want to plot the bode diagram, but I don't know how to. Is it possible to plot the bode from fft since what I know, bode is magnitude and pase shift vs frequency, so I only need to find the angle of each data?.When, I searching for bode, I found there must be input and output for data, but my data consists only vibration, and I also read about transfer function, how I get the transfer function from my data (excel)?

Comment: Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28274717/how-to-plot-bode-diagram-of-a-signal-using-fft-in-matlab

Comment: @cgiovanardi surely thank you for the reference, but unfortunately I only know about the fft matlab code there, there rest is I don't know. Would you explain to me if you have any hint?